# How to make dynamic google map in block?

Tags: blocks, google-maps

I want to make block with two links that lead to different gmaps position. Also gmaps is in that block. 
So, block haves address text with two location and by clicking on that location i want that gmaps change the position of marker without reloading all page. So it is need to be dynamic block. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

you could start by creating a custom module if you want , there's plenty of tutorials on the drupal website to help you get started then , in the block template add the js you need to create that map with the coordinates you want  . or using views , like in [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2607702) 
 hope it helps